# Stop the hiding event

Tags: javascript, jquery, superfish

I have a Superfish menu item that has 2 text inputs, I want to make sure the menu does not get closed (hidden) if one of these fields has the user's focus.

I have everything for this except I don't know how to stop the Superfish Hide event execution.

```
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish({
            onBeforeHide: function () {
                $('ul.sf-menu').find('input[type=text], input[type=password]').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(':focus')) {
                        //need code to stop Superfish Hide execution here
                    }
                });
            },
            delay: 500
        });
    });
```

How can I stop the hide event execution?

Comment: I've never worked with superfish before, but my guess would be to return `false`

Comment: @cfs: that only stops the current function, but not the parent function that does the actual hiding.

Comment: What event is firing?  Is it mouse off, but the cursor is still in the text box?  Answer could vary.

Comment: @Ted Johnson: yeah, it's `mouseOut` of the DIV while still having a cursor in one of the text inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is fixed. I had to change the plugin code itself:

```
if ($ul.find('input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus ').length  == 0){

     $ul.stop(true, true).animate(o.animationOut, speed, function () {
     var $this = $(this);                        
     o.onHide.call($this);                        
             });
     }
 else{
      $(this).addClass(o.hoverClass);
     }
```

The idea is to count a number of text inputs that have user's focus at the moment, if there's more than one, add the `hoverClass` which makes the menu item stay visible. If there's no focused items, it will proceed with hiding as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like `event.PreventDefault()`? http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Or if that's not man enough for the job a `return false;` should stop everything in its tracks.

[edit] You could try doing a `.stop()` on the animations for the element

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish({
        onBeforeHide: function (liElement) {
            $('ul.sf-menu').find('input[type=text], input[type=password]').each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':focus')) {
                    $(liElement).stop();
                }
            });
        },
        delay: 500
    });
});
```

Or if that doesn't help you may have to cancel the mouseleave event that the menu registers for its `li` elements. Excuse the pseudocode in the `if`

```
$("ul.sf-menu").on("mouseleave", "li:having(ul)", function(){
        $(this).find('input[type=text], input[type=password]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':focus')) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: it seems like it's only stopping my `onBeforeHide` function, but continues to actually hide the menu item

Comment: How about if you allow a parameter into your function and then call `$(param).stop();` before `return false;`?

Comment: The actual hide event is a `menu.on("mouseleave.superfish", "li:having(ul)", function(){})` so you could try cancelling that with your own mouseleave function.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need with superfish 1.7.4.
Here is my solution, tested with Chrome 31, IE 10 and IE 10 Compatibility mode IE 7 :

```
 /*to store the input which gets the focus (mouse click or tab key)*/
    var inputFocused = null;
    $('#mymenu').superfish({
    delay: 500
    , speed: 'fast'
    , disableHI: true
    , onInit: function(){
        var ul = $(this);
        var inputs = ul.find('input[type=text], input[type=password]');
        inputs.each(function(index, elt){
        $(elt).on('click', function(event){
            inputFocused = $(elt);
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
        $(document).on('click', function(event){
                            /*to allow people to choose to quit the menu*/
            inputFocused = null;
        });
        $(elt).on('keyup', function(event){
            inputFocused = $(elt);
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
}
, onHide: function(){
var ul = $(this);
if(inputFocused != null && ul.find(inputFocused).length > 0){
    ul.css('display', 'block');
    inputFocused.focus();
}
}
});
```